# How to ensure that onCreateView() for a fragment class is called each time I swipe to it's tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

In my program, I have 2 implemented  `tabs` using `fragments`. I've placed an `EditText` inside Tab2. I want to write all my main code for `Tab2` inside `onCreateView`() of `fragment` `Tab2`, so that every time I swipe over to `Tab2`, this same code is executed. To test whether `onCreateView`() was being called every time I swiped to Tab2, I wrote the following statement in `onCreateView`() of `Tab2`:

```
text.setText("default");
```

Now when I run the app and swipe to Tab2- I see 'default' written. Now if I change this text manually, then swipe over to Tab1 and come back to Tab2- I still see this same text written. This obviously means that `onCreateView`() was not called again when I swiped to Tab2 for the 2nd time? How do I fix this?

**Tab2.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Tab2 extends Fragment
{



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setRetainInstance(false);
    final View rootView;
    rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);

    text.setText("default");
    return rootView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nirvan.diary30;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;  
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
public static int itemPosition;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);



}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new      ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in onCreateView? Maybe this can be accomplished on some other way?

Comment: see `setUserVisibleHint` method

Comment: In tab1 I plan to have a list of subjects. On clicking each one and then swiping back to tab2- a new page should load with an EditText. I plan to have a SAVE button also in Tab2 to save the user-entered text. So if the user selects one subject in Tab1, goes to tab2 and writes some text, comes back to Tab1, selects another subject- then when he swipes back to Tab2, an empty EditText should show now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewPager`

```
ViewPager viewPager;
```

Try to use `setOnPageChangeListener`in `MainActivity`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             if(mFragmentList.size() > position && mFragmentList.get(position) instanceof Tab2)
             {
                 ((Tab2)mFragmentList.get(position)).changeText("changed text")
             }
 // you can use interface insted 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

in `Tab2`

```
public void changeText(String string){
  text.setText(string);
}
```

**Update** `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
public static int itemPosition;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentLists = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

     viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             if(mFragmentList.size() > position && mFragmentList.get(position) instanceof Tab2)
             {
                 ((Tab2)mFragmentList.get(position)).changeText("changed text")
             }
 // you can use interface insted 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    mFragmentLists = adapter.getFragements();
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public List<Fragment> getFragements()
    {
      return mFragmentList;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I copy this code into my onCreateView() , I get an error saying ` non static method cannot be referenced from static context` . To solve this I made a ViewPager object. But to initialize that object I have to supply a View object...which view object do i supply to the ViewPager constructor?

Comment: @Ghost, as we need to this method in `MainActivity` and `viewpager` is instance of `ViewPager`.. please see edited code

Comment: Now it's saying ' viewPager might not have been initialized' . My question in the last comment was that if I write an initialization statement for this....what view object do I pass ?

Comment: You have already intialized ` viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: Do I put this code into mainActivity.java? What is mFragmentList here?

Comment: Yes.. you should add this in mainactivity.  Where `mFragmentList` is the list which is used in `ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: Ok I did that. mFragmentLists and mFragmentList is supposed to be the same variable, right? Once I correct that the code, I get an error saying 'Cannot resolve method changeText() '